# How to get file/Document from document set using ms flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I want to get a Document/file from document set inside document library using ms flow/Power automate.Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Note: the trigger is not in the same library, i want to get another library document in custom list When an item is created/Modified Trigger flow.**

Comment: How do you identify the document you want to get? If you have the document identifier, just use that with the Get File action. A document set is just a folder (on steroids), so should not impact on getting a file by its identifier.

Comment: I am getting the document set using GetFolderbyServerRelativeURL Action, but i am not getting  File Identifier here.

Comment: What action is that? Are you using a http request with REST?

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, you can use action like get file content, get file metadata or other actions like the pic below. If you use URL, you can use the actions using path.
[image]